# CMYK Images displaying as negatives

Tags: assets, rgb, cmyk, pimcore, pimcore-v5

CMYK Images that are uploaded are displaying as negatives.
I downloaded the adobe icc color profiles and entered the paths in the settings as described in the documentation without success.

[image: cmyk image displaying as negative]

Comment: Adding the ICC profiles was the correct step. You maybe just need to remove all the thumbnails (in the clear cache menu) to regenerate them. Do you have imagick installed?

Comment: I already tried unsuccessfully. ImageMagick is installed. Even reinstalling ImageMagick did not help. Can it be that I have the wrong ICC profiles? I have the profiles from the Adobe page from the official documentation.

Comment: Check this forum topic: https://talk.pimcore.org/t/cmyk-to-rgb-displaying-as-negative/908/17 You might be missing lcms delegate. See the last post

Comment: new installation with lcms-delegate didn't help me either

Comment: Does this happen with ALL CMYK images or only with some? Did you check in the system requirements check ob Pimcore really recognizes your Imagick.

Comment: everything is checked and it happens with all cmyk images.